# Would Pan go Super Saiyan in Dragon Ball Super?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

Since now the author at least knows how to draw a female Super Saiyan such as Kale and Caulifla, would Pan go Super Saiyan in *Dragon Ball Super*?

Comment: Basically we cannot answer this, since pan is still a child and so far no child has been show to transform into a ssj. If she will later be a ssj is also purely speculation, because we don't know when super will end and if there will be a shown time skip

Comment: It is not an opinion based question. It has a legitimate answer. We do not know yet, but from past history and recent changes (Introduction of female Super Saiyans), it is highly probable that Pan may go Super. There are plenty of acceptable questions where this is the case, i.e. No answer as of this moment but possible to answer in the future.

Answer (score 3):

This answer contains spoilers!

> Kale and Caulifla transforming proves that there can now be female super saiyans from either universes.
>
>  Pan - less than one year old, breaks a robot/machine, flies through the stratosphere and carries 3 little people while flying. My deduction about pan's power:
>
>  * My first thought is comparing her to goten/trunks, as they were able to transform into super saiyans at an early age which could be due to goku + vegeta having higher power levels at that time(just assuming that since it's shown that goku was weaker when he was young - again this could be linked to his father being weak), therefore it could possibly be assumed that she will benefit from this as well since gohan would actually have been the strongest at the time of conception(this is backed up by pans feat of flying and her strength for a baby).
>  * My second would be how gohan had so much potential, even surpassed vegata and goku in the past(in the cell and majin boo sagas), constantly getting strong due to his emotions(his potential drawn out through anger as well as his 'Mystic' or 'Ultimate' form), and that may have also passed down to her.
>  * My third is how she's always there watching the fighting as a baby, maybe learning from it(with flying maybe she tried to imitate someone).
>  * And my last would be the whole beerus situation - pan was exposed to all of that power, whilst not even being born yet(while she was still developing in the womb - it could have affected her own powers).
>
>  So, with this all said i think there is a strong possibility that she could become super saiyan when she grows up. She is still a baby so this is heavily theory-based, so it is not definate and with that said,it is also not solid evidence however, it does make her becoming super saiyan seem more realisic.

Answer (score 1):

She might go Super Saiyan, she might not.

I have read that the only reason she didn't go Super Saiyan during *Dragon Ball GT* is because Akira Toriyama (the creator of *Dragon Ball*) did not know how a female Super Saiyan should look like. She has a high power rating, and has Saiyan blood, so she has the potential.

And there are female Super Saiyans already, like Caulifla. So, who knows.

Comment: Adding a source where the reason why Pan wasn't Super in the original DBZ will help improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well the only reason she never went Super Saiyan in GT was because Akira Toriyama stated that Pan and Bulla never had the incentive to go Super Saiyan and that at the time he did not know how a female Super Saiyan would look. Since we now have female Super Saiyans, Caulifla and Kale, Toriyama would be able to make Pan a Super Saiyan. Especially since she was exposed to all that power when doing the ritual for Goku to go Super Saiyan God, she could definitely go Super Saiyan.

There was so much power that Videl herself had blonde Super Saiyan-like hair. Videl herself didn't go Super Saiyan but probably from all the energy surrounding her and the energy from Pan inside her she had blonde hair. Since Toriyama now has a way for female Saiyans to go Super Saiyan I believe that both Pan and Bulla will be able to go Super Saiyan. I believe that Bulla has a higher chance since she is coming directly from Vegeta himself and would be half Saiyan and half human like Goten, Trunks, and Gohan. Since Pan is only like a quarter Saiyan it would be harder for her to achieve Super Saiyan. This is all just what I believe and I believe that Pan and Bulla has more than enough potential to go Super Saiyan just like Goku, Vegeta, Trunks, Goten, Gohan, Cabba, Caulifla, and Kale. Even in GT Goku Jr. was able to go Super Saiyan and he was like 1/16 of a Saiyan which is way less than any of the other half-breeds.

It all depends on if Toriyama decides to go past the ending of Z in Super or if he just decides to leave the end of Z the ultimate end to Dragon Ball itself and whatever happens after we'll never know. I'm hoping that they go past the ending of Z especially since the whole purpose of the anime is to sell merchandise like toys and video games. I don't know about toys but I do know that games like Xenoverse 2 and the new Fighterz that is coming out soon is making them a ton of money. And since Bandai Namco themselves said there will be more Xenoverse games we know that those will rake in a ton of money. The series as a whole depends on us as the fans in order to continue the anime and manga. We just need to keep supporting Dragon Ball as much as we can.